# How to add fragment into round input field in android studio xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to create something like this:

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkqsg.jpg)

The "555" is the input by the user only, the rest is static

I searched many online tutorials but many of them are only show how to create rounded input field but not including the image on the left side of the field. So how can i add image on the left side and let user input at the same time ? Exactly like the image above?

Comment: can you put the code you used ?

Comment: There is a simple method in EditText for adding image on left side,

<EditText
        ...     
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/my_icon" />

Comment: check this : https://bloglotto.amebaownd.com/posts/15503991/

Comment: @Teyhhh use this library https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject